# Symfony2 - Sonata Admin datagrid error no results

Tags: symfony, datagrid, sonata-admin

I've some trouble with the Sonata Admin on Symfony2, i've a user list with many filters butone of them use a 'doctrine_orm_callback'

```
            'callback' => function (QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value) {
                if($value['value'] === null)
                    return;

                    $queryBuilder->leftJoin($alias.'.ad', 'a');
                    $queryBuilder->groupBy('a.id');
                    $queryBuilder->orderBy('a.id', $value['value']);
                    $queryBuilder->setMaxResults(1);

                return;
            },
```

When i've no result i have this exception 'No result was found for query although at least one row was expected.'

How could tell to Sonata a function 'getOneOrNullResult' like ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i've that dirty thing but actually works.

```
'callback' => function (QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value) {
                if($value['value'] === null)
                    return;

                    $qb = clone $queryBuilder;
                    $results = $qb
                        ->setMaxResults(1)
                        ->getQuery()
                        ->getResult()
                    ;

                    if(count($results) > 0) {
                        $queryBuilder->leftJoin($alias.'.ad', 'a');
                        $queryBuilder->groupBy('a.id');
                        $queryBuilder->orderBy('a.id', $value['value']);
                        $queryBuilder->setMaxResults(1);
                    }

                return;
            },
```